# Writing a simple function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

This function needs to take a data frame with three variables and four observations (a, b, c and d) and calculate `(a/c) / (b/d)`.

for example:

```
df <- data.frame(female = c("White", "White", "non-White", "non-White"),
             male = c("White", "non-White", "White", "non-White"),
             n = c(85, 5, 5, 10))
 xtabs(n ~ female + male, df)
```

the function would have to calculate `(85 * 10) / (5 * 5)` and return a result of `34`. 
I have previously tried this:

```
 oddsRatio <- function(x){
  x %>%
    summarise(oddsratio = (n[1] * n[4]) / (n[2] * n[3]))
} 
oddsRatio(df)
```

but this produced the answer in a table and also didn't work universally on other data frames with 4 observations and 3 variables in the way that I wanted it to.

Comment: this would give you a number `oddsRation <- function(x){
  (x$n[1] * x$n[4])/(x$n[2] * x$n[3])
}`   it computes the ratio based on the position of the values on `df`, is this what you want? What if the rows are sorted in a different way?

Comment: c1au61o_HH thank you so much this is EXACTLY what I needed! I have been trying to write this function for days thank you so much for your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways.  No packages are needed.

**1)** Create a logical that picks out the diagonals and then subset xt with that and with its negative.

```
xt <- xtabs(n ~ female + male, df)

is.diag <- row(xt) == col(xt)
prod(xt[is.diag]) / prod(xt[!is.diag])
## [1] 34
```

**2)** or pick out the diagonal and antidiagonal using indexes:

```
prod(xt[c(1, 4)]) / prod(xt[2:3])
## [1] 34
```

**3)** If the values of xt are known to be strictly positive then we could take the log, multiply that by `c(1, -1, -1, 1)`, sum and take exp to get back:

```
exp(sum(log(xt) * c(1, -1, -1, 1)))
## [1] 34
```

**4)**  If you are performing this calculation to test independence of the factors you could just directly use `fisher.test` .  [Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) calculates the maximum likelihood estimate of the odds ratio given the table's marginals using the hypergeometric distribution.  The null hypothesis is that the two factors are independent, i.e. the odds ratio equals 1, and in the example below it is rejected, i.e. the factors are not independent. Note that the confidence interval does not contain 1.

```
fisher.test(xt)
```

giving:

```
        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  xt
p-value = 2.435e-07
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
   6.951076 174.962113
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  31.48572
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` way of doing it

```
df %>%
  summarize(oddsRatio = prod(n[female == male])/prod(n[female != male]))
```

As a function that returns a number

```
oddsRatio <- function(x) {
  x %>%
    summarize(oddsRatio = prod(n[female == male])/prod(n[female != male])) %>%
    pull(oddsRatio)
}

oddsRatio(df)
# 34
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with(df, prod(ifelse(female==male, n, 1/n)))

[1] 34
```

This is similar to @cnicol's solution but aviods any need for tidyverse.